# Chrome taking a "screenshot" after 500ms of page load?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, chromium

I read this:

> In Chrome I see a jerkiness some time
>   after page load or a location change
>
> Chrome creates a screenshot of the
>   current page 500 milliseconds after
>   the page loads, or, and this is the
>   trickier part, 500ms after every time
>   the location, including the URL
>   fragment (the stuff behind the #),
>   changes. There is currently no perfect
>   work around for this problem. In order
>   to avoid jerkiness in your animation
>   try to not animate while this happens.

on http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/speed/html5/

What the heck is that? I am trying to make some animations occuring in the beginning more smoothly, but I think I am hit with that problem, but not sure.

Comment: This is not related to programming at all?

Comment: My guess would be that it is the screenshot used in the new tab page.

Comment: @EboMike: well... I assume the question he wants to pose is: how do I avoid doing animations while Chrome is taking a screenshot?